# Extremely large numbers showing up in output file

Tags: c++

I have a program which takes in a data file full of numbers (5 digits - 1 digit), sorts it, then calculates the average.

Problem is, for some strange reason, I seem to be getting random numbers. For example, here's an example of the output file (it changes everytime for some reason):

```
-1634367306
-1461109043
-542664683
-542664639
-542664491
-2
-1
-1
0
0
```

And towards the end...

```
2003150324
2003165000
2003165000
2003165011
2003165011
2003165090
2003195799
2003196010
2003196054
2003284685
2003834952
2006176524
2006176524
2006221796
2006221796
```

The numbers from the input file are from 0 - 99999, so I have no clue why these numbers are showing up.

Here's my code concurrently for it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void getData(int[], int);
void outputData(int[], int);
double calcAverage(int[], int);
int findHighest(int[], int);
int findLowest(int[], int);
void removeDuplicates(int[], int);
void selectionSort (int[], int);

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 1000;
    int table[SIZE];

    getData(table, SIZE);
    selectionSort(table, SIZE);

    cout << "Highest number: " << findHighest(table, SIZE) << endl;
    cout << "Lowest number: " << findLowest(table, SIZE) << endl;
    cout << "Average: " << calcAverage(table, SIZE) << endl;

    outputData(table, SIZE);
}

/** selectionSort
**  - Sorts an array of numbers
**/
void selectionSort(int array[], int size) {
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;
        for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++) {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++) {
            if (array[index] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}


/** getData
** - Opens a file of a set of numbers
** - Reads data from file into an array of numbers
**/
void getData(int table[], int size) {
    ifstream iFile;
    iFile.open("numbers.txt");

    if (!iFile) {
        cout << "File failed to load, please try again." << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        iFile >> table[i];
    }
    iFile.close();
}

/** outputData
** - outputs a sorted array of numbers to a text file
**/
void outputData(int table[], int size) {
    ofstream oFile;
    oFile.open("entry.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        oFile << table[i] << endl;
    }
    oFile.close();
}

/** calcAverage
** - Calculate and return average of all data entries
**/
double calcAverage(int table[], int size)  {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        total += table[i];
    }
    return total / size;
}

/** findHighest
** - return highest number from array
**/
int findHighest(int table[], int size) {
    int high = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (table[i] > high)
            high = table[i];
    }
    return high;
}

/** findLowest
** - return lowest number from array
**/
int findLowest(int table[], int size) {
    int low = findHighest(table, size);
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (table[i] < low)
            low = table[i];
    }
    return low;
}
```

Typical results of the Highest, Lowest, Average, show:

> Highest number: 2006221796 Lowest number: 2006221796 Average: 2.71055e
>   + 007

No clue what I'm getting wrong here.  No compiler errors, and I'm pretty sure everything was initialized properly.

Comment: Uninitialized data is the cause.  Dunno where it's coming from yet.

Comment: For example, in the methods findHighest and findLowest, I have integers initialized to 0, instead of leaving them uninitialized, so I'm not sure where these are coming from either.

Comment: Are you sure there are (at least) a thousand numbers in the file?

Comment: How is the input file arranged?  In other words what separates each integer?  Is it white space?  Is it a `\n`? Are they `\t\n`?  Please post a few lines of the input file to help us understand its content.

Comment: Input file is unordered, and has 921 lines of numbers, each has its own line

Comment: For `findHighest` it's best to initialize `high` to `table[0]` and start the loop at `1`. Similarly for `findLowest`.

Comment: So you're trying to read 79 more numbers from the file than are actually in it. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Gah, as I was typing this I just realized this. Maybe it could be that

Comment: So what could I do in this case?  The homework itself requires an array of size 1k, yet the input file is only 921 integers long, is there any way to deal with the other 79?

Comment: The `getData` function needs modification to stop reading after the last input file line, regardless of whether the input file is 2, 42, 100, or 921 lines long.  Look at your favorite stream reference.  Here is one that could help: [std::basic_ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).  The `fail()` method can be checked at the same time as the array bounds in the for loop.

Comment: You absolutely should trace how your program works on some 2-item or 3-item arrays, say {4, 5}, {-4, -5} or {2, 3, 1}. Do it with a paper and pencil and you will find out yourself what's going on here. **Side note:** of course you know you don't have to *sort* the array prior to finding its minimum, maximum and average value?

Answer (score 4):

'Input file is unordered, and has 921 lines of numbers' - so how your progam will know how many items were read into the array? You declare `const int SIZE = 1000;` and use that value as a range of sorting – so you're sorting 79 uninitialized items of the array, data which were not in your input,

Comment: A quick fix for this would be to make `getData` return how many items it successfully read, and then in `main()` use that value instead of `SIZE` thereafter.  Of course , it'd be even better to store the items in a container which remembers how many items are in it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I here nominate `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing your input routine something like this in order to determine the number of elements that were actually read in:

```
int getData(int table[], int maxsize) {

    ifstream iFile("numbers.txt");
    if (!iFile) {
        cerr << "Can't open number.txt\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int n, i = 0;
    while (iFile >> n) {
        if (i >= maxsize) {
            cerr << "Table overflow\n";
            break;
        }
        table[i++] = n;
    }

    iFile.close();

    return i; // return the number of elements read
}
```

Comment: Ultimately, the loop condition above will take a look at the `fail` bit and other parts of the `ios_base::iostate` flags.